# Since 2 days I get stuttering audio and xruns in Ubuntu Studio

Tags: sound, jack

It's fine for some minutes after reboot and then I get constant xruns and stuttering audio.

I can provoke the issue by trying to record audio from the internal mic.
I didn't manage to get any audio on the recording - it's maybe related.

#### Things I tried

- restarting Jack
- doubling buffer
- rebooting

any pointer?

#### Infos

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-37-lowlatency
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-2820QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 7,7 GiB of RAM
```

`Linux ThinkPad-W520 5.4.0-37-lowlatency #41-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 3 19:52:07 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
cat .config/autojack/autojackrc 
[DEFAULT]
jack = True
driver = alsa
chan-in = 0
chan-out = 0
rate = 48000
frame = 256
period = 2
zframe = 128
xdev = 
pulse-in = pulse_in
pulse-out = pulse_out
pj-in-con = 1
pj-out-con = 1
a2j = True
dev = PCH,0,0
usbauto = True
usb-single = False
usbdev = 
log-level = 19
```

```
cat .config/jack/conf.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
JACK settings, as persisted by D-Bus object.
You probably don't want to edit this because
it will be overwritten next time jackdbus saves.
-->
<!-- Wed Jun 17 09:49:09 2020 -->
<jack>
 <engine>
  <option name="driver">alsa</option>
 </engine>
 <drivers>
  <driver name="alsa">
   <option name="device">hw:PCH,0,0</option>
   <option name="capture">none</option>
   <option name="playback">none</option>
   <option name="rate">48000</option>
   <option name="period">256</option>
   <option name="nperiods">2</option>
  </driver>
  <driver name="firewire">
  </driver>
  <driver name="alsarawmidi">
  </driver>
  <driver name="loopback">
  </driver>
  <driver name="netone">
  </driver>
  <driver name="dummy">
  </driver>
  <driver name="net">
  </driver>
 </drivers>
 <internals>
  <internal name="netadapter">
  </internal>
  <internal name="audioadapter">
  </internal>
  <internal name="profiler">
   <option name="cpu-load">true</option>
  </internal>
  <internal name="netmanager">
  </internal>
 </internals>
</jack>
```

```
Wed Jun 17 13:41:40 2020: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
13:41:42.304 XRUN callback (26 skipped).
Wed Jun 17 13:41:42 2020: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client pulse_in finished after current callback
Wed Jun 17 13:41:42 2020: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = pulse_out was not finished, state = Running
Wed Jun 17 13:41:42 2020: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client a2j finished after current callback
Wed Jun 17 13:41:42 2020: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
13:41:44.311 XRUN callback (6 skipped).
15:20:09.856 XRUN callback (175433).
15:27:16.929 XRUN callback (175434).
```

Comment: i would try to  disable pulseaudio bridge in Ubuntu Studio Controls (i don't use UbuntuStudio so it is just test)

Comment: Thanks, I can't reproduce the problem right now but there is still no sound from the mic. In the evening I can test some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems stopped after I took the machine apart for cleaning and application of new thermal paste. Why didn't the OS tell me that the system was overheating?!